# Is there a way to "pull" and "up" with docker-compose without creating build folders in testing enviroment?

Tags: docker-compose

So, i have a docker-compose file that has a build command in each service. In development, docker-compose up works ok. In test enviroment, i want to docker-compose pull and docker-compose build the images, and it works ok, except it needs the folder in build command created in testing server.

Is it really necesary or is there a way to pull and up the containers without create the build folders in the testing server?

Answer (score 0):

There is `docker-compose up --no-build`

Comment: A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.